# enabled gzip -- running out of threads

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, compression

I enabled gzip in apache2 and started load testing -- I am seeing a lot of keep alives state busy state -- 95% of the web server worker threads are being used at any given time

While CPU is ok, I am assuming the issue is that the compression is making the threads wait longer --

What could be the issue -- where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What do you compress ? Everything except images ?
Size of content ?

Did you do a test load before activating compression ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check your KeepAlive timeout settings, also from the shell run:

http -l (assuming you are using httpd on RHEL or a derivative distro, not sure about the apachectl equivalent).

You'll see prefork.c or worker.c from there modify you httpd.conf IFModule section, dependent on whether you are running prefok / worker, you can raise the number of apache threads there.

On a cautionary note you should only allow for a number of threads you can comfortably fit in memory, this will vary depending on what modules you have loaded in, you can see a write up [here](http://www.saiweb.co.uk/linux/optimizing-apache-for-high-load-sites-part-3) I suggest reading all 3 parts.